# Rename file names in Linux based on conditions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file-rename

I have some files in Linux directory like below.

```
email_Tracking_export_2018_08_26.zip
email_Tracking_export_2018_08_27.zip
email_Tracking_export_2018_08_28.zip
email_Tracking_export_2018_08_29.zip
email_Tracking_export_2018_09_03.zip
email_Tracking_export_history_Novemeber.zip
email_Tracking_export_history_December.zip
email_Tracking_export_history_january.zip
email_Tracking_export_history_february.zip
email_Tracking_export_history_march.zip
email_Tracking_export_history_April.zip
```

Now I want to change the files names to be like below.

```
email_Tracking_export_2018_08_26.zip
email_Tracking_export_2018_08_27.zip
email_Tracking_export_2018_08_28.zip
email_Tracking_export_2018_08_29.zip
email_Tracking_export_2018_09_03.zip
email_Tracking_export_2017_11_01.zip
email_Tracking_export_2017_12_01.zip
email_Tracking_export_2018_01_01.zip
email_Tracking_export_2018_02_01.zip
email_Tracking_export_2018_03_01.zip
email_Tracking_export_2018_04_01.zip
```

Conditions:

1. If the file names are in yyyy-mm-dd format then leave them as is
2. if the file names are in Alphabetical form convert to yyyy-mm-dd
3. if month has passed in that particular year than leave as is if not then year should be previous year.

How can I achive that in `bash/Linux`

Comment: Having just the month name in the filename isn't enough to convert it to a `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Show us the real/close to real input.

Comment: @nmr I think this it is a very important that you solve it on your own because it might make your understanding of the subject more clearer. Sounds like a homework problem too. Best of Luck!!

Comment: For a name like `email_Tracking_export_history_Novemeber.zip` how do you know what year or day of the month to use? Is it always `2018_mm_01`?

Comment: @Barmar For ex: November 2018 has not occured so the year should be 2017 and date can be any default date

Comment: You should say that in the conditions in the question. What part of this is giving you trouble? You need to to show what you've tried and ask specific questions about the parts you can't figure out. Don't just ask for how to do the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for f in email_Tracking_export_*.zip; do
  case "$f" in
  email_Tracking_export_????_??_??.zip) : ignore ;;
  *) date=$(stat -c %Y "$f") # mod time in seconds
     fmtdate=$(date --date="@$date" +%Y_%m_%d) # formatted
     mv "$f" email_Tracking_export_$fmtdate.zip
  ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: your answer is replacing `email_Tracking_export_history_Novemeber.zip
email_Tracking_export_history_December.zip
email_Tracking_export_history_january.zip
email_Tracking_export_history_february.zip
email_Tracking_export_history_march.zip
email_Tracking_export_history_April.zip` of these to just one file `email_Tracking_export_2018_09_07.zip`

Comment: Well, if you just created all of the files and they have today's modification time, sure.

Answer (score 0):

### Here are the steps in small parts which you can find answers of and execute as a bash script,

1. Make a key value pair of mapping, which maps a month to its numerical value. (Take care of lowercase/uppercase)
2. For each file, check their format.
3. Generate the new name for each file.
4. Then, use the `mv` command to rename the file with the new name.